# navigationItem.title shifts to left

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to set title of my view using

```
myViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Test";
```

It works fine and title displays in center. But when I am assigning any variable like

```
myViewController.navigationItem.title = dynamicTitle;
```

It is shifting to left side near to leftbarbutton. How can I fix it? Navigation bar has a rightbarbutton also.

Comment: Lenght of your title?

Comment: Ok. I thought that your dynamicTitle could havec somme "blank" characters (space) at the end so it could be like that.

Comment: Thanks @Larme. Yes i missed the same. dynamicTitle having many white spaces at its end, due to this its getting shifted to left side. Thanks again.